# Let's see if you can solve this one, open items hell

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to calculate Open column based on the following scenario.

1. For a unique sales order + sales_order_item, if Billed_Item is NULL, Open = Order_Quantity.
2. If Billed_Item is not null then Open = Order_Quantity -
   Billed_Quantity until the sum of Billed_Quantity for that unique
   sales_order + sales_order_item becomes equal to Order_Quantity. Once
   that sum(Billed_Quantity for unique sales_order+sales_order_item) =
   Order_Quantity, then Open becomes = 0 for all sales_order + sales_order_item.
3. For reference, check 1209549436, 1261171592 for both result and expected result table. See how for 1209549436 all Open are marked as 0 because the sum of billed_qty = order_quantity but for 1261171592 it is order - billed because the order is not completed. Weird one yeah!!
4. And if it was not enough, I have to create a view out of it.

### My currect query

```
SELECT
so.sales_order AS 'Sales_Order',
li.so_item 'Sales_Order_Item',
li.order_quantity AS 'Order_Quantity',
IF(bi.bill_item IS NULL, li.order_quantity, li.order_quantity - bi.bill_qty) AS Open,
li.so_net_price AS 'Sales_Order_Net_Price',
(li.order_quantity * li.so_net_price) AS 'Sales_Order_Net_Value',
bi.bill_item AS 'Billed_Item',
bi.bill_qty AS 'Billed_Quantity',
bi.bill_doc_date AS 'Billed_Document_Date'
FROM sap_sales_order so
LEFT JOIN sap_so_line_item li
ON so.sales_order = li.sales_order
LEFT JOIN sap_billing bi
ON so.sales_order = bi.sales_order
AND (li.so_item = bi.bill_item or bi.bill_item = 0);
```

### Result

```
+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Sales_Order | Sales_Order_Item | Order_Quantity | Open  | Sales_Order_Net_Price | Sales_Order_Net_Value | Billed_Item | Billed_Quantity | Billed_Document_Date |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |  1655 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             845 | 2015-11-23           |
| 1209549436  |               20 |           8800 |     0 |                  1.00 |               8800.00 | 20          |            8800 | 2015-11-23           |
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |  1450 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |            1050 | 2015-12-14           |
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |  2000 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             500 | 2015-12-21           |
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |  2395 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             105 | 2015-12-21           |
| 1261171592  |               10 |           1500 |    70 |                  0.78 |               1170.00 | 10          |            1430 | 2017-02-16           |
| 1261171581  |               10 |           7698 |  7698 |                  0.78 |               6004.44 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               10 |          90000 | 90000 |                  1.00 |              90000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               20 |          75000 | 75000 |                  1.00 |              75000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               30 |              1 |     1 |             145000.00 |             145000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               40 |              1 |     1 |              60000.00 |              60000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

### Expected result(Check Open Column)

```
+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Sales_Order | Sales_Order_Item | Order_Quantity | Open  | Sales_Order_Net_Price | Sales_Order_Net_Value | Billed_Item | Billed_Quantity | Billed_Document_Date |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |     0 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             845 | 2015-11-23           |
| 1209549436  |               20 |           8800 |     0 |                  1.00 |               8800.00 | 20          |            8800 | 2015-11-23           |
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |     0 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |            1050 | 2015-12-14           |
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |     0 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             500 | 2015-12-21           |
| 1209549436  |               10 |           2500 |     0 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             105 | 2015-12-21           |
| 1261171592  |               10 |           1500 |    70 |                  0.78 |               1170.00 | 10          |            1430 | 2017-02-16           |
| 1261171581  |               10 |           7698 |  7698 |                  0.78 |               6004.44 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               10 |          90000 | 90000 |                  1.00 |              90000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               20 |          75000 | 75000 |                  1.00 |              75000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               30 |              1 |     1 |             145000.00 |             145000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
| 1270396732  |               40 |              1 |     1 |              60000.00 |              60000.00 | NULL        |            NULL | NULL                 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

### SQL Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `sap_sales_order` (
  `sales_order` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `order_reason` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_create_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sold_to_party` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_po` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id_name_1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `sap_sales_order` (`sales_order`, `order_reason`, `so_create_on`, `sold_to_party`, `customer_po`, `site_id_name_1`, `import_date`) VALUES
('1270396732', NULL, '2017-02-02', 'A1', NULL, 'GHI', '2017-03-13'),
('1261171592', NULL, '2016-12-15', 'A1', NULL, 'GHI', '2017-03-13'),
('1209549436', NULL, '2015-09-23', '45342', 'PPQQRR', 'DEF', '2017-03-13'),
('1261171581', NULL, '2016-12-15', '45342', 'OMI1212', 'DEF', '2017-03-13');

CREATE TABLE `sap_so_line_item` (
  `so_item` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `material` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_quantity` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_net_price` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_net_value` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_order` char(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `import_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `sap_so_line_item` (`so_item`, `material`, `description`, `order_quantity`, `so_net_price`, `so_net_value`, `sales_order`, `import_date`) VALUES
~(10, 'M1', 'K1', 7698, '0.78', '6006.44', '1261171581', '2017-03-13'),
~(10, 'M4', 'K4', 2500, '1.00', '2500.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
~(10, 'M4', 'K4', 90000, '1.00', '90000.00', '1270396732', '2017-03-13'),
~(20, 'M3', 'K3', 75000, '1.00', '75000.00', '1270396732', '2017-03-13'),
~(30, 'M4', 'K4', 1, '145000.00', '145000.00', '1270396732', '2017-03-13'),
~(40, 'M1', 'K1', 1, '60000.00', '60000.00', '1270396732', '2017-03-13'),
~(20, 'M2', 'K2', 8800, '1.00', '8800.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
(10, 'M5', 'K5', 1500, '0.78', '1170.00', '1261171592', '2017-03-13');

CREATE TABLE `sap_billing` (
  `bill_item` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `bill_qty` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_doc_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_doc` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `bill_net_value` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_order` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `import_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `sap_billing` (`bill_item`, `bill_qty`, `bill_doc_date`, `bill_doc`, `bill_net_value`, `sales_order`, `import_date`) VALUES
('10', 845, '2015-11-23', '3206790137', '845.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('20', 8800, '2015-11-23', '3206790137', '8800.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 1050, '2015-12-14', '3209056079', '1050.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 500, '2015-12-21', '3209763880', '500.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 105, '2015-12-21', '3209763885', '105.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 1430, '2017-02-16', '3251725740', '1154.40', '1261171592', '2017-03-13');
```

Comment: add a bounty... people will make time to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider derived tables joining current query as is with an aggregate query grouped by *Sales_Order* and *Sales_Order_Item*. Then in outer query run your conditional `IF` logic again to calculate *Open*:

```
SELECT unit.Sales_Order, unit.Sales_Order_Item, unit.Order_Quantity, 
       IF(unit.Order_Quantity = agg.Sum_Bill_Quantity, 0, unit.Open) AS 'Open', 
       unit.Sales_Order_Net_Price, unit.Sales_Order_Net_Value, unit.Billed_Item, 
       unit.Billed_Quantity, unit.Billed_Document_Date
FROM

    (SELECT so.sales_order AS 'Sales_Order',
            li.so_item AS 'Sales_Order_Item',
            li.order_quantity AS 'Order_Quantity',
            IF(bi.bill_item IS NULL, li.order_quantity,
            li.order_quantity - bi.bill_qty) AS Open,
            li.so_net_price AS 'Sales_Order_Net_Price',
            (li.order_quantity * li.so_net_price) AS 'Sales_Order_Net_Value',
            bi.bill_item AS 'Billed_Item',
            bi.bill_qty AS 'Billed_Quantity',
            bi.bill_doc_date AS 'Billed_Document_Date'
    FROM sap_sales_order so
    LEFT JOIN sap_so_line_item li
    ON so.sales_order = li.sales_order
    LEFT JOIN sap_billing bi
    ON so.sales_order = bi.sales_order
    AND (li.so_item = bi.bill_item or bi.bill_item = 0)
   ) As unit

INNER JOIN

   (SELECT so.sales_order AS 'Sales_Order', 
           li.so_item AS 'Sales_Order_Item', 
           SUM(bi.bill_qty) AS Sum_Bill_Quantity 
    FROM sap_sales_order so
    LEFT JOIN sap_so_line_item li
    ON so.sales_order = li.sales_order
    LEFT JOIN sap_billing bi
    ON so.sales_order = bi.sales_order
    AND (li.so_item = bi.bill_item or bi.bill_item = 0)
    GROUP BY so.sales_order, 
             li.so_item
   ) As agg

ON unit.Sales_Order = agg.Sales_Order 
AND unit.Sales_Order_Item = agg.Sales_Order_Item
ORDER BY unit.Sales_Order, unit.Sales_Order_Item;
```

And to create view, use [`CREATE VIEW view_name AS select_statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Comment: We have a MVP! Thank you sir for spending time on my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is incorrect for what you are trying to do:

IF(bi.bill_item IS NULL, li.order_quantity, li.order_quantity - bi.bill_qty)

This means: 
If bill_item is null - set open to order_quantity 
Otherwise set open to order_quantity - bill_qty

You would need a sub select statement to evaluate the sum of the bill_qty across for the current row across all rows that have the same order_num.

For example:

```
select
li.order_quantity - 
(select(sum(innerli.bill_qty) FROM sap_sales_order innerso
LEFT JOIN sap_so_line_item innerli
ON innerso.sales_order = innerli.sales_order
LEFT JOIN sap_billing innerbi
ON innerso.sales_order = innerbi.sales_order
AND (innerli.so_item = innerbi.bill_item or innerbi.bill_item = 0) 
and innerso.sales_order = so.sales_order)  //IMPORTANT LINE TO TIE THE SUB SELECT TO THE MAIN

FROM sap_sales_order so
LEFT JOIN sap_so_line_item li
ON so.sales_order = li.sales_order
LEFT JOIN sap_billing bi
ON so.sales_order = bi.sales_order
AND (li.so_item = bi.bill_item or bi.bill_item = 0);
```

Comment: Your query is giving errors. Is the - in 2nd row supposed to be a comma?

Comment: Ah sorry, looks like I missed a '(' before the select.  It should not be a comma - it is attempting to subtract all sales order billed quantity across that sales order from the total ordered on that sales order.

Comment: Still not working. Can you correct the above code and not do indent please?

Comment: I found an additional syntax mistake and removed the indentation.  I do not have access to these tables, so I cannot verify the solution, but this is intended as a way forward toward your solution, not a final result.